# I want to add multiple attribute on one go

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute

How can i add multiple attributes in one script.

namespace Backadmin\Grid\Setup;

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Eav setup factory
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'clothing_material',
            [
                'group' => 'General',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Clothing Material',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'backend' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 50,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Magento2 -> Create Multiselect Product Attribute Programmatically**
`['code' => 'code_of_the_attribute',
        'attribute_set' => '*',
        'label' => 'Concern',
        'attribute_group' => 'Extra Content',
        'type' => 'text',
        'input' => 'multiselect',
        'option' => ['values' => [
            'Option 1',
            'Option 2',
            'Option 3',
            ],
        ],
        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
        'unit' => '',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'sort_order' => 2,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'searchable' => true,
        'filterable' => true,
        'used_for_promo_rule' => true,
        'comparable' => false,
        'wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => false,
        'used_for_sort_by' => false, ]`

Comment: Please change Information according to You

Comment: It's Helpful to You@avesh